# Prevent Screen Capture on Zoom Android SDK

Tags: android, screenshot, flag-secure

I have integrated **Zoom SDK** into android application where teacher can take live classes and student would access it. The problem is I need to prevent taking screenshots or screen-record while live meeting is going on. **MeetingActivity** is getting intented when meeting is started. But I do not find any override methods in the **MeetingActivity** onCreate to enable the below code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Also I cannot edit the sdk code. Kindly suggest me a possible way to handle this.

Comment: Most likely, you cannot handle this, if you cannot override `onCreate()` to set `FLAG_SECURE`. You would need to ask Zoom to add some hooks for this in their SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am  not able to intent to a newly created activity which is extending MeetingActivity. Atleast this must happen right

Comment: https://devforum.zoom.us/t/how-to-disable-screen-recorder-and-screen-shoret-in-zoom-sdk/5851 - I referred this , this seems to be working well ! Thanks for your response